# Android bluetooth communication does not work

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, chat

Greeings

I have Micromax A110 (android os 4.0.4) and samsung galaxy pop (android os 2.2.1)

downloaded the bluetoothchat sample from sdk and tried running it

when i tried to coonect from micromax to samsung it throws exception with message (e.getMessage)
 "connect: Connection is not created (failed or aborted)."

when i tried connect from samsung to micromax it says

```
"Service discovery failed"
```

Now i changed the UUID to
 private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("fafafafa-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");

now micromax to samsung same exception message
    "connect: Connection is not created (failed or aborted)."
but samsung to micromax it says 
    "connection refused"

Then i changed the line

```
 tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

to

```
tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                Method m;
                m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

as per info in stackoverflow

Now 
now micromax to samsung same exception message
    "connect: Connection is not created (failed or aborted)."

but samsung to micromax says
       "connected" and when i type some message it sends to micromax

But the micromax side no message disaplayed  and still waiting for client connections
 socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

I couldn't' understand what is going on. The interesting thing is the same used to work well
around a year back. Don't' know any software upgrade happened in these mobiles
Please let me know what could be the problem.

### code from the sample

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread");
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                Method m;
                m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
            setName("ConnectThread");

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                connectionFailed();
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: solved it by doing the factory reset of the micromax canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by doing the factory reset of the micromax A110